# I do not understand how var foo = [true].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)) works, specifically what is [true] is doing?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at var args = [true].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)); what I understand is that it is trying to add the arguments of a function to the end of an array. However I am not familier with the syntax [true], having true inside an array. What is it trying to achive. if an array exist then add? if does not exist make an array and then add?

```
  extend: function extend(/* dest, source1, source2, ...*/) {
        var args = [true].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        return copyInto.apply(this, args);
    },
```

Comment: That would prepend `true` to the beginning of the array.

Comment: just starting  with array that has one element who's value is `true`

Comment: It's just an array with one element that has the value `true`. I guess the `copyInto` function needs a boolean value as its first argument.

Answer (score 1):

[true] creates an array of one boolean element which is true.

For example this is also valid:

```
[true, false, true]
[0,1,2]
```

[true].concat(some other array) returns an array which is a concatenation of [true] and some other array

For example

```
[true].concat([true, false, false])
```

equals to [true, true, false, false]